# Sum of two Gamma

Tags: probability

Does anyone know what the sum of the following two Random variables is?

Sum of two independent Gamma(a,b) and Gamma(a,c). That is two random variables with same shape parameter but different scale parameters.

Any good approximations for their pdf?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The pdf of the sum of two independent Gamma distributions $$S=\Gamma(a,b)+\Gamma(c,d)$$

Notice different scale and shape parameter has generalized integer gamma distribution.

However one can approximate the pdf by another Gamma distribution using Welch-Satterthwaite approximation.